# Center Text in a Flutter Column

Tags: flutter

I am looking for help in centering the "mytitle" text in a column.

I tried `centerTitle: true,` between 'mytitle' and 'overflow', but it did not work:

```
Card(
 child: Container(
  child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
          Padding(
              child:
                Text(
                  mytitle,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: CustomTheme.bodyText1.override(
                  fontFamily: 'Noto Sans',
                  fontSize: 24,
                  color: txtcolor),               
                )
            )
        ]
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `crossAxisAlignment` as follow:

```
Container(
alignment: Alignment.center,
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
          Padding(
              child:
                Text(
                  mytitle,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: CustomTheme.bodyText1.override(
                  fontFamily: 'Noto Sans',
                  fontSize: 24,
                  color: txtcolor),               
                )
            )
        ]
    )
)
```

for more information see [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout). In summary, you can set the layout of `Column` in two directions. The first one is the vertical axis (`MainAxis`) and the second one is the horizontal (`crossAxis`) direction. `Row` has the same feature but its `mainAixs` and `crossAxis` is opposite.

Comment: I should have put that line in my original code snippet above. I tried crossAxisAlignment but it still looks a little off center.

Comment: so, try using center alignment for container and text too.

Comment: I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: all good, thank you!

Comment: I tried your code with mainAxis = center and crossAxis = center and I haven't been able to reproduce it. I did leave out your custom theme and font family because I don't have those and I wonder if that's where the issue is coming in.

Comment: @CountryMusic happy to help, your welcome...